# How can the minimum size of a mdf file be reduce from it's creation size

Tags: sql, sql-server

A db was created with the MDF file set at 200GB, since the data has been moved to a secondary file group I would like to reset the minimum file size on the primary filegroup to 1GB(large enough to hold sys tables data)

Answer (score 0):

Shrink the file. If the file_id is 1:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (1, 1024);
```